# Hosting a sub-domain content in Azure

Tags: azure

In our site, we want to host some subdomain content in Azure. We have pushed the content into blob storage like this, for example:

https://strgAcctName.blob.core.windows.net/name1/ourFolder/ourFile.htm

Now, we want to map everything from this "subdomain" in our site, for example:

subdomain.oursite.com/ourFolder/ourFile.htm

.... to above.

We are ready to set the DNS record in our server to an Azure IP address. But, I think we are not sure how to get the IP Address because https://strgAcctName.blob.core.windows.net/name1 cannot be pinged.

What are we missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a CNAME record to point to your blob storage endpoint.

So in your DNS provider configuration:

```
CNAME subdomain.yourdomain.com -> endpoint.blob.core.windows.net
```

It looks like you'd want SSL for this subdomain, and currently, Azure Blob storage doesn't support HTTPS on custom end points, so you'd have to do the following:

- configure Azure CDN for your blob storage
- Set up CNAME for your subdomain to the Azure CDN
- Enable HTTPS on the CDN

The previous stuff is all documented in-depth [on Azure's own documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-map-content-to-custom-domain).